# Add a div around every picture, colored black. PHP or HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How could I make a border around every picture on the web-page?
**My webpage shows all the pictures inside a folder.** And that is from where my need comes for a border because it looks too ugly with out it.

The code: index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Goat Imager</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCC00">
<?
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    print $num."<br>";
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image"/>'."<br><br><br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I was thinking of two options:

Option a.) Put some kind of a command that will change add a border to every picture on the webpage at the end of loading.

Option b.) (Which I perfer) Change the code I gave so it adds a border to every new picture displayed from the folder.

Comment: Why css is not an option?

Comment: Ah well ok it can be css.

Comment: Then why not using a `<style>` tag if css is not an option?

Comment: Just look down please at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use CSS?
Insert this directly after the title tag.

```
<style>
    img { border: 5px solid #000000; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Goat Imager</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCC00">
<?
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    print $num."<br>";
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" style="border:2px solid"/>'."<br><br><br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have just added  the `border style` attribute to the `image` tag.. Hope this will work without affecting the css of other images..

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to make this happen, simply:

```
img {
   border: 3px solid black;
}
```

For example. This will apply to every image in your website. And in case you want to exclude something like logo or header images, just specify it in your CSS-code, like this:

```
.content img {
   border: 3px solid black;
}
```

And of course in your HTML-code, wrap your content around `<div class="content"> CONTENT HERE!! </div>` so it applies correctly.

Using JavaScript for this kind of a thing is almost guaranteed to cause some issues with the heaviness of your website, I would not recommend that, neither do I recommend any PHP solutions for this.